# How to check if a property exists?

Tags: ant

How do I check the existence of a property using Ant?

I am open to the use of `ant-contrib`, if Ant doesn't provide a similar thing.

Also, `ant-contrib` has an assert task, which provides `exists`, but the assertion is not what I need here since I would prefer a boolean return value.

Comment: <if>
     <not>
      <equals arg1="${myprop}" arg2="$${myprop}" />
     </not>
     <then>
  <echo message="Property exists" />
     </then>
     <else>
         <echo message="Property does not exist" />
     </else>
    </if>

Comment: Please edit the above comment if someone knows how to, not sure if code tags using 4 indents works here in the comment.

Comment: "if" task is only supported with Ant-contrib which I would not recommend to use for serious development.

Comment: @funkybro - agreed. Why raudi? ant-contrib rocks, and brings Ant one step closer to Gradle.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the [Condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) task with an [isset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) condition.

```
<project default="test">

  <property name="a" value="a"/>

  <target name="test">

    <condition property="a.set" else="false">
      <isset property="a"/>
    </condition>

    <condition property="b.set" else="false">
      <isset property="b"/>
    </condition>

    <echo message="a set ? ${a.set}"/>
    <echo message="b set ? ${b.set}"/>

  </target>
</project>
```

Output:

```
test:
     [echo] a set ? true
     [echo] b set ? false
```

Comment: Be sure to **leave out** the ${} around the property names in `<condition>` and `<isset>`.

Comment: @sudocode but if "a" is empty (value=" ") a.set will be false, not true. why?????

Answer (score 12):

Since Ant 1.9.1 it is possible to use "if" and "unless" attributes. You can use these new attributes if you add the 2 namespaces xmlns:if="ant:if" and xmlns:unless="ant:unless" to the project.

```
<!DOCTYPE project>
<project xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">
  <property unless:set="property" name="property.is.set" value="false"/>
  <property if:set="property" name="property.is.set" value="true"/>
  <echo>${property.is.set}</echo>
</project>
```

see also https://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html

Comment: In fact you should use Ant >= 1.9.3 as the first implementation in Ant 1.9.1 had bugs related to if/unless feature !