# ANT Fails with Library Project (ActionBarSherlock, HoloEverywhere)

Tags: android, ant, build, actionbarsherlock, library-project

Yesterday i was able to fix all my previous issues and simple android apps are running without any problems.

After setting everything up for them i tried to do the same for 3 of my more complex apps. All those apps use ActionBarSherlock and ViewPagerIndicator.

The first issue was that if i have a project (without holoeverywhere) ant can't compile because it tries to add a class which was added already. I know which library is causing the issue -> android-support-v4.jar but i can't remove it. It's required for ViewPagerIndicator and ActionBarSherlock.

The second more annoying issue is, that as soon as i add HoloEverywhere (it requires ActionBarSherlock as dependency) it gives me the following error:

```
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] /Users/**/Project Librarys/HoloEverywhere/HoloEverywhereLib/res/values/styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock'.
     [aapt] /Users/**/Project Librarys/HoloEverywhere/HoloEverywhereLib/res/values/styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock'.
     [aapt] /Users/**/Project Librarys/HoloEverywhere/HoloEverywhereLib/res/values-v14/styles.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock'.
     [aapt] /Users/**/Project Librarys/HoloEverywhere/HoloEverywhereLib/res/values/styles.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'.
     [aapt] /Users/**/Project Librarys/HoloEverywhere/HoloEverywhereLib/res/values-v14/styles.xml:14: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'.
     [aapt] /Users/**/Project Librarys/HoloEverywhere/HoloEverywhereLib/res/values/styles.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'.
     [aapt] /Users/**/Project Librarys/HoloEverywhere/HoloEverywhereLib/res/values/styles.xml:66: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow'.
     [aapt] /Users/**/Project Librarys/HoloEverywhere/HoloEverywhereLib/res/values/styles.xml:86: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow'.
     [aapt] /Users/**/Project Librarys/HoloEverywhere/HoloEverywhereLib/res/values/styles.xml:106: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar.ForceOverflow'.
```

I know it says that the references to the ActionBarSherlock style is missing but why? I use the original ant-script and even if i was able to fix all paths to the libraries (ant ignores the defined project.properties in the build.xml of a library project) it is not able to build.

Any hints or ideas?

everything above seems ok.

```
Buildfile: /Users/**/Zuzzle/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 20
 [checkenv] Installed at /Entwicklung/android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: SplashscreenActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Application
     [echo] Switching between debug and non debug build: Deleting previous compilation output...
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/**/Zuzzle/bin/classes

-build-setup:
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for SplashscreenActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.1
[gettarget] API level:        16
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/**/Zuzzle/bin/classes
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for SplashscreenActivity...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'release'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 20
 [checkenv] Installed at /Entwicklung/android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: library
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library
     [echo] Switching between debug and non debug build: Deleting previous compilation output...
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/**/Project Librarys/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/bin/classes

-build-setup:
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for library...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.1
[gettarget] API level:        16
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/**/Project Librarys/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/bin/classes
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for library...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 8 source files to /Users/**/Project Librarys/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/bin/classes
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...
      [jar] Building jar: /Users/**/Project Librarys/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/bin/classes.jar

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /Users/**/Project Librarys/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /Users/**/Project Librarys/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/bin/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-release-prompt-for-password:

-release-nosign:
     [echo] 
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/**/Project Librarys/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/**/Project Librarys/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/**/Project Librarys/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/**/Project Librarys/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library/bin/build.prop

-release-sign:

-post-build:

release:

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 20
 [checkenv] Installed at /Entwicklung/android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: library
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library
     [echo] Switching between debug and non debug build: Deleting previous compilation output...
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/**/Project Librarys/ActionBarSherlock/library/bin/classes

-build-setup:
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for library...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.1
[gettarget] API level:        16
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/**/Project Librarys/ActionBarSherlock/library/bin/classes
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for library...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 82 source files to /Users/**/Project Librarys/ActionBarSherlock/library/bin/classes
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...
      [jar] Building jar: /Users/**/Project Librarys/ActionBarSherlock/library/bin/classes.jar

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /Users/**/Project Librarys/ActionBarSherlock/library/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /Users/**/Project Librarys/ActionBarSherlock/library/bin/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-release-prompt-for-password:

-release-nosign:
     [echo] 
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/**/Project Librarys/ActionBarSherlock/library/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/**/Project Librarys/ActionBarSherlock/library/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/**/Project Librarys/ActionBarSherlock/library/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/**/Project Librarys/ActionBarSherlock/library/bin/build.prop

-release-sign:

-post-build:

release:

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 20
 [checkenv] Installed at /Entwicklung/android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: library
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library
     [echo] Switching between debug and non debug build: Deleting previous compilation output...
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/**/Project Librarys/HoloEverywhere/HoloEverywhereLib/bin/classes

-build-setup:
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for library...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.1
[gettarget] API level:        16
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/**/Project Librarys/HoloEverywhere/HoloEverywhereLib/bin/classes
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for library...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
```

the ** in the path are only to hide the real path. the script knows the correct path.

Comment: "I know which library is causing the issue -> android-support-v4.jar but i can't remove it. It's required for ViewPagerIndicator and ActionBarSherlock." -- one or both of those will have their own copies; you do not need one yourself. However, since you decided not to post the real error (instead, posting other random output **not** showing the error), it is difficult to give you more specific advice. "ant ignores the defined project.properties in the build.xml of a library project" -- it works for me.

Comment: what works for you? that ant does ignore same libs? do you have any idea why the ant script isn't building the app? i would really appraciate any help

Comment: "what works for me?" -- Ant pays attention to `project.properties` of library projects, for their library project dependencies.

Comment: yeah i know but somehow ant does something wrong because holoeverywhere can't find any ressources from the actionbarsherlock library (i tried a few different variants, removed abs from main project, used it in both holoeveryhwere + main project and so on...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was now able to fix my issue. It seems my build.xml was corrupt and it made any issues.

If someone wants to rename his application package, here is the solution i found in the web:

```
<target name="-package-resources" depends="-crunch">
        <!-- only package resources if *not* a library project -->
        <do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not package resources..." >
            <aapt executable="${aapt}"
                    command="package"
                    versioncode="${package.manifest.version.code}"
                    versionname="${package.manifest.version.name}"
                    debug="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
                    manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}"
                    assets="${asset.absolute.dir}"
                    androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}"
                    apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
                    nocrunch="${build.packaging.nocrunch}"
                    resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}"
                    resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}"
                    libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"
                    libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages"
                    previousBuildType="${build.last.target}"
                    buildType="${build.target}"
                    ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}"
                    manifestpackage="${package.manifest.name}">
                <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
                <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
                <!-- <nocompress /> forces no compression on any files in assets or res/raw -->
                <!-- <nocompress extension="xml" /> forces no compression on specific file extensions in assets and res/raw -->
            </aapt>
        </do-only-if-not-library>
    </target>
```

This is the cleanest variant i think.

Comment: add libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path" to this will make this perfect.

Comment: Actually your answer helped me I was not trying to answer.

Comment: @DineshVenkata no problem. i'm still always happy about new tips. even if i changed to a different technology in the meantime :)

Comment: I have a doubt how do check if ${package.manifest.name} has been set and then execute this target?

Comment: @DineshVenkata something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079203/ant-how-to-check-if-a-property-exists ?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work in my case I put a validation for the <target> but it still executes the code.

Comment: perhaps you should open a separat question here on stackoverflow.